# Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is about the math calculations and operations in excel. To do this three cells are required. For example, if you're doing addition one cell for the first value, one cell for the second value and one more cell which contains the formula/operation. The third cell would also display the results. Is it possible to do all this in one cell only? In one cell you can input the values to be added,subtracted and so on. The formula is also in one cell. The operation will also be in one cell and the result will be displayed in one cell. Basically it would be input, process and output in one cell. Is that possible. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: You can write all your formula =10+5 and you will get result all in the same cell

Comment: You can use 2 cells one with your input A1 and A2 the second =A2+A1 after enabling iteration in Excel options

Comment: @Supersam Your first answer works. Just need to put equal sign then press enter and the answer displays on one cell and it replaced the input (=10+5) with the answer 15. I think this the one I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can write all **your formula =10+5** in the same cell and you will get the result 15
all in the same cell
For any calculation you can do the same